# What's the the apex:relatedlist 'list' parameter for Order Product History?

Tags: visualforce, related-list, orderitem

I'm trying to add the 'Order Product History' related list for an OrderItem (aka 'Order Product') to a Visualforce page that uses 'OrderItem' as the standardController:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" standardController="OrderItem">
    <apex:relatedList list="OrderItemHistories" />
</apex:page>
```

This give a runtime error that the 'list' parameter is incorrect.  Does anyone know what the correct 'list' parameter is?

Here is a quick screenshot of the related list I am trying to add:

[image: Standard 'Order Product' page with Order Product History related list]

Comment: Typically it is the `relationshipName` for the relationship. Have you tried just `OrderItems`

Comment: Tested it out quickly, and it works...just added the answer below.

Comment: That doesn't always work. For instance see `ActivityHistory`.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `apex:relatedList` visualforce tag, you need to use the `relationshipName` value in the describe data for that object.

[image: Order Describe of Order Item Child Relationship]

The above screenshot shows OrderItem with the child relationship name of `OrderItems`

So this should work:

```
<apex:relatedList list="OrderItems"/>
```

In some instances, `apex:relatedList` does not support certain standard child relationships. For instance the Field History related list has a value of `Histories` for the `relationshipName` describe property for all objects, but if used you will receive this exception:

> 'Histories' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Order

There doesn't seem to be a clear delineation between what is and isn't supported amongst standard related lists, but all custom ones are.

Comment: Are you saying that this related list is not supported?